# Help identifying diode

Tags: diodes, identification

so I have this diode that is under a transformer on a battery charger. I was looking for faults on it with a thermal camera and noticed the one next to it was glowing at over 120C . I removed the hot one and it is pretty much shorted as shows 0.03 in both directions with the diode test. Iv also got a peak tester dca 75 and it won't even identify it as a component.

The one next to it is marked with V21 and is just a regular looking brown / orange looking colour and is glass. 
I would go on what the dca 75 says, but each time it tests the working one, the vf goes up.

It's been so hot that it's burnt 99% of the markings off it, but it looks to be paired with the one next to it.
The problem is I can't seem to find a replacement for it. "V21 Zener diode" just brings up an smd diode sot 23 package and not a through hole glass diode like this.

[image]

Comment: Can you draw a schematic and post it? You can generally come up with a replacement if you can figure out the circuit. V21 is probably an in-house number.

Comment: Ya Vince Patraon is right .. its just an in-house number. The diode is a simple zener diode.

Comment: I am guessing the diodes are a two diode rectifier for one of the transformer windings as the low voltage side is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SMD devices typically are marked with random letters/numbers, but through-hole devices usually try to use markings that resemble the actual name.

"V21" sounds like the BAV21, which is a general-purpose diode [made](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/products/discretes/diodes-rectifiers/small-signal-diodes/BAV21.html) [by](http://www.nxp.com/products/discretes-and-logic/diodes/switching-diodes/general-purpose-diodes:BAV20_BAV21) [many](http://www.vishay.com/product?docid=85543) [manufacturers](http://www.mccsemi.com/product.aspx?id=4780&cid=103).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense as I think it's 250v coming in, have ordered a few of this's and will see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a standard IN4148 diode. Google for it and see pictures.
If it is hot it means a lot of current is going thru. Check your
schematics.